# Imagemagick - Incorrectly identifies the dimensions for .jpg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

Imagemagick is not identifying the correct width x height for .jpg images.  I'm on OSX (10.6 Snow Leopard). I have a .jpg image. When viewing the image information in Finder it states that the Dimensions are 2592 x 3888.  When I use 'identify image.jpg' it returns 3888 x 2592.  If I open the image in Preview and save as .png then do 'identify image.png' it correctly returns 2592 x 3888. Does anybody know what is going on?

The primary issue is that I'm using Imagemagick as part of the Paperclip Gem in a Ruby on Rails website.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Preview.app to rotate the JPEG for viewing?

Even if you did this days, weeks or months ago, and if you didn't save the rotated image, Preview.app will remember this rotation (and also tell Finder about it) and continue to display this image in rotated mode.

When you convert this to PNG, it will create a rotated PNG.

So, ImageMagick is correct all the way through, and Finder/Preview.app did play a nice trick on you...   :-)